# Why I cannot copy with a variable name in windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a `c:\test` directory which has a text file `var_list.txt` with these 3 lines:

> abc 
>  xyz 
>  def

I have a `C:\test\source` directory which has a text file `source_file.txt`.

I have a `C:\test\target` directory which is empty.

I want to write a windows batch file which do these tasks:

1. read `var_list.txt` line by line in a variable
2. for each line copy the `source_file.txt` from `C:\test\source` directory to
   `C:\test\target` directory with the file name also having the variable line appended to it in its name

So when I run this windows batch file, I want it to create these 3 files:

1. target_file_abc.txt
2. target_file_xyz.txt
3. target_file_def.txt

So I create a windows batch file `create_target_files.bat` in `c:\test` directory with these contents:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (var_list.txt) do (
  echo line=%%a
  copy /Y /V C:\test\source\source_file.txt C:\test\target\target_file_%a%.txt
)
pause
```

When I run it I get this output:

> line=abc 
>           1 file(s) copied. 
>  line=xyz 
>           1 file(s) copied. 
>  line=def 
>           1 file(s) copied. 
>  Press any key to continue . . .

But in `C:\test\target` directory only 1 file `target_file_.txt` is created. Why 3 files are not created with variable names?

Answer (score 1):

There is a small mistake in your code.

```
copy /Y /V C:\test\source\source_file.txt C:\test\target\target_file_%a%.txt
```

In this line of code, you are using `%a%` instead of `%%a`.

Since you did not assign the variable, `%a%` would give you a blank string.

Therefore, all copied files are named **target_file_.txt** and they are overwritten by the last file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that :

```bat
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('Type "C:\test\var_list.txt"') do (
    Set "line=%%a"
    echo !line!
    Copy /y /v "C:\test\source\source_file.txt" "C:\test\target\target_file_!line!.txt"
)
pause & exit
```

For more information how and when to use **[Enabledelayedexpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)**